# Colour font installation (emoji) in Maverick Meerkat 

Tags: 10.10, gnome, fonts, font-rendering

I've tried to install this [Apple Emoji TTF font](http://cl.ly/2L2A0a1v472N0u3h2p0U) but even the Font Viewer doesn't render them correctly.

Does anyone have an idea about whether this kind of font is supported in 10.10/Gnome 2.32 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing it uses some exotic Apple extension. I can't find anything that will open it. You probably have to be using an Apple machine. That sounds typical of Apple.

Comment: Why am I not surprised !

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative, installing the Symbola font made it so that characters in the emoji Unicode space displayed properly for me in Firefox/Chromium.
You have two options:

- Either you manually download the font from a web site like [this one](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) and manually install it or
- You install the [Ancient-Fonts-package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/all/ttf-ancient-fonts/filelist) via `apt-get install ttf-ancient-fonts`

Answer (score 1):

this file isn't shown on OS X either. While I read somewhere that the Emoji files theirselves are hidden on OS X, this font is only readable by Font Book 3 (which is only available on OS X 10.7, Lion). Font Book 3 = Emoji support :)

OS X 10.6 = Font Book 2 (for now)